# jQuery & Supersized file error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scripting, gallery

I use **jquery 1.9 and migration plugin**, now I have added supersized gallery, but I get always js error in my gallery page, `undefined 404 (Not Found)`, if I see this error in the developer tools, then I get only:

```
tmp.innerHTML = wrap[1] + elem.replace( rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>" ) + wrap[2];
```

My jQuery file is from [jquery cdn](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js), and dev.tool says the error on line: *6469*

I can't understood what 'can't be found', what must u edit to fix this?

Comment: Could you post the URL of your gallery page here?

Comment: At the moment is the site only on localhost, i have also tried with older version of jquery, combine other supersized versions, but not success

Comment: Very hard to say at the moment what could cause it, could you try to create a fiddle to reproduce the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/. Also most likely this is not jQuery error but something else, are you using Chrome dev tools for debugging?